# How to create a custom filling with ListPlot

Tags: plotting, graphics, filling

We have the following simple example

```
data = {{1, 1.5}, {2, 3}, {3, 5}, {4, -1}, {5, -9}, {6, 1}, {7, 10}};
L0 = ListPlot[data, Joined -> True, Axes -> False, Frame -> True, 
PlotRange -> {{1, 7}, {-10, 10}}]
```

[image]

The joined line divides the plane into two areas (upper and lower).
Is there any easy way to paint, let's say green the upper area and red the lower, while the line should be still visible?

Many thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
data2 = {{1, 10}, {7, 10}}; data = {{1, 1.5}, {2, 3}, {3, 
   5}, {4, -1}, {5, -9}, {6, 1}, {7, 10}}; L0 = 
 ListPlot[{data2, data}, Joined -> True, Axes -> False, Frame -> True,
   PlotRange -> {{1, 7}, {-10, 10}}, 
  Filling -> {1 -> {{2}, Green}, 2 -> {Bottom, Red}}, 
  PlotStyle -> {Automatic, {Black, Thickness[0.02]}}]
```

[image]

you can also use `Show` as follows:

```
L0 = ListPlot[{data}, Joined -> True, Axes -> False, Frame -> True, 
  PlotRange -> {{1, 7}, {-10, 10}}, Filling -> {1 -> { Bottom, Red}} ,
   PlotStyle -> {Black, Thickness[0.02]}];
 L1 =ListPlot[{data}, Joined -> True, Axes -> False, Frame -> True, 
      PlotRange -> {{1, 7}, {-10, 10}}, Filling -> {1 -> { Top, Green}} , 
      PlotStyle -> {Black, Thickness[0.02]}];
    Show[L0, L1]
```

Comment: The line between the two areas is not visible any more

Answer (score 2):

An alternative syntax using `FillingStyle` explicitly

[image]

```
data = {{1, 1.5}, {2, 3}, {3, 5}, {4, -1}, {5, -9}, {6, 1}, {7, 10}};
L0 = ListPlot[data, Joined -> True, Axes -> False, Frame -> True, 
  PlotRange -> {{1, 7}, {-10, 10}}, 
  PlotStyle -> Directive[Black, AbsoluteThickness[5]], 
  Filling -> {1 -> Top, 1 -> Bottom}, FillingStyle -> {Green, Red}]
```

[image]